# Calculating skewness, kurtosis and 5th moment from moment definition

Tags: probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I need to calculate the skewness, kurtosis and 5th moment of a data set. Here are the definitions of skew and kurtosis:

$f_{skew} = \frac{\frac{\sum(Y_i - \bar Y)^3}{N}}{s^3}$

$f_{kurtosis} = \frac{\frac{\sum(Y_i - \bar Y)^4}{N}}{s^4}$

with $s$ defined as

$s^2 = \frac{\sum (Y_i - \bar Y)^2}{N}$

A moment about the mean, $x_0$, is:

$<(Y-Y_0)^j> = \sum_{i=1}^N p_i (Y_i - Y_0)^j $

My question is: using the definition of the moment, how do I compute $f_{skew}$ and $f_{kurtosis}$ and the $5$th moment?

Comment: What does "400 Hz" have to do with anything?  Why did you include that point if it is indeed irrelevant?

Comment: Just to give an idea of how big $N$ is (if that even matters)

Comment: Clearly the size of $N$ is irrelevant, and not used anywhere in the question.  What specifically would be different if you used "$40000000000$ Hz"?  And what is a "module" anyway?  And what does it have to do with the question?

Comment: $N$ is explicit in the formulas. I was not sure if that would be a relevant piece of additional information to give or not. I guess that for some large distributions that could make a difference? I'm not sure. The main point is not that, though. I just want to know how to get to those formulas (if they are actually correct)

Comment: The module is a sensor that I'm gathering information.

Comment: Please answer my question:  "And what does it have to do with the question?"

Comment: God. I don't know if I should draw for you. $N$ comes from the 400 Hz device. That's it. If it's not relevant to you, just ignore it.

Comment: God.  I'm trying to teach you how to ask a good question, and you cannot see the irrelevancies.  If you had, you might be better an *answering* your own questions.  I urge you to start to try.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, it didn't seem you are trying to teach anything. You could have suggested removing the information from the question, but you simply kept asking me the same thing. It is clear that I'm not sure if the information is relevant or not (by my second comment). If you are SURE that it is not relevant, I would remove it from the question. Next time, just try another approach besides the "I'm gonna prove my point by you telling me what the problem is".